# Hadoop YARN SLS (Scheduler Load Simulator)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I run the simulator with following command:

```
bin/slsrun.sh --input-rumen = <sample-data/2jobs2min-rumen-jh.json>
```

and it gave the following error:

```
-su: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Note: PWD is $HADOOP_ROOT/share/hadoop/tools/sls

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial site

Answer (score 0):

It comes with your Hadoop distribution. The script is located in the tools directory: `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/sls/bin/slsrun.sh`. A description of its usage is available at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-sls/SchedulerLoadSimulator.html. I successfully followed the steps on my Hadoop 2.8.0 installation.